# Scala Akka Fault Tolerance/Supervision not working

Tags: scala, akka, fault-tolerance, akka-actor, akka-supervision

I am trying to implement fault tolerance within my actor system for my Scala project, to identify errors and handle them. I am using **Classic** actors. Each supervisor actor has 5 child actors, if one of these child actors fails, I want to restart that actor, and log the error, and as I mentioned, handle the problem that caused this actor to fail.

I implemented a `One-For-One SupervisorStrategy` in my Supervisor actor class as such:

```
override val supervisorStrategy =
    OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 5, withinTimeRange = 1.minute) {
      case e: ArithmeticException =>
        logger.error(s"Supervisor: $e from $sender; Restarting!")
        Restart
      case e: NullPointerException =>
        logger.error(s"Supervisor: $e from $sender; Restarting!")
        Restart
      case e: IllegalArgumentException =>
        logger.error(s"Supervisor: $e from $sender; Restarting!")
        Restart
      case _: Exception =>
        logger.error(s"Supervisor: Unknown exception from $sender; Escalating!")
        Restart 
    }
```

I added a `throw new NullPointerException` in one of the methods I know is called in every actor, as the system never/rarely fails. But, in the `log` file, I do not get what I expect, but the following:

```
13:41:19.893 [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21] ERROR akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy - null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

I have looked at so many examples, as well as the Akka documentation for fault tolerance for both types and classic actors, but I cannot get this to work.

**EDIT**

After doing some more research, I saw that a potential reason for the error I am getting could be caused by an infinite cycle in the child actor, whereby it throws an error, restarts, throws an error etc.

So I took a different approach, where in the supervisor actor, I added a variable `sentError = false`, then in one of the supervisor methods that tells the child actors to start working, I added the following:

```
if(!errorSent){
   errorSent = true
   actor ! new NullPointerException
}
```

And when a child actor receives an error, they throw it. I took this approach so that this only ever happens once, to avoid the cycle. However, unfortunately this did not change the output, and I still got the error mentioned above.

Comment: When you say the exception is thrown in every actor in the system, does it get thrown in the supervising actor?  The supervising actor doesn't supervise itself, the failure of the supervising actor goes to its parent

Comment: No, sorry I could have explained that better. I have since tried a new approach, I will add an edit. @LeviRamsey